# IF statement for dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataset that looks like this.

| Conatct 1 | Contact 2 | Contact 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | XYZ | STU |
| NA | NA | LMN |
| ABC | PQR | NA |

I'm trying to write a new column which will consolidate the contact information from the three different columns into one consolidated column such that if Contact 1 is NA then contact information from Contact 2 will be picked up and if Contact 2 is also empty then Contact 3 will get picked up. Below is the code I have so far.

```
def rm_contact(row):
   if row["LOB Contact #1"] != "NA":
     return row["Contact 1"]      
   else:
     return row["Contact 2"] 

df2 = df2.assign(rm=df2.apply(rm_contact, axis=1))
```

The else part of the code doesn't seem to work. So even though Contact 1 is NA the details from Contact 2 or Contact 3 don't get filled in properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use if `NA` is missing value - back filling missing values per rows and then select first column:

```
cols = ["Contact 1","Contact 2","Contact 3"]
df2['rm'] = df2[cols].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

If `NA` is string first replace values to missing `NaN`s:

```
df2['rm'] = df2[cols].replace('NA',np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple case of chain together `fillna()` in order you want values to be picked

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Contact 1   Contact 2   Contact 3
NA  XYZ STU
NA  NA  LMN
ABC PQR NA
"""), sep="\t")

df.assign(rm_contact=df["Contact 1"].fillna(df["Contact 2"]).fillna(df["Contact 3"]))
```

|  | Contact 1 | Contact 2 | Contact 3 | rm_contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | XYZ | STU | XYZ |
| 1 | nan | nan | LMN | LMN |
| 2 | ABC | PQR | nan | ABC |